Crash: Thread 1: "Tried accessing the col index for a variable that is a row head:0x6000021a7b60.marker{id: 8773}.brokenNegError{id: 23368}" in swift
I am developing a chat application for iOS in swift. I am using different cells for text message, images, files etc having attributed labels in each cell to display formatted text, to sync with web side chat.
Issue is, when I scroll tableView with large data it crashes with the above mentioned description. Also tableView shows warnings on each cell and has abnormal behaviour on visible cell count and offset.
Realtime chat: And often cells overlap when message comes from Realtime(Sockets), and at some point it crashes randomly with the description in the heading.
I have searched a lot but couldn't find appropriate solution about this crash.
NOTE: It works fine when I replace attributed labels with simple text label.
NOTE: Top and Bottom Constraints in the AutoLayout are in such a way that cell automatically resize according to content width.
